# How to mount MTP device without logging out?

Tags: mount, mtp

I have lubuntu 14.04 installed in my laptop. When I plug my xperia m to the laptop, the storages doesn't automount. But once I logout and log back in keeping the phone plugged in, it shows both the internal storage and the external memory card of the phone.

Could somebody please tell me a way so that I don't have to keeping logging out and logging back in to access my phone memory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again on its own. I didn't have to do anything lol.